# get post_posts empty with ampersand in title

Tags: wordpress, post

I have tried with below scenario, but both are getting empty results if post title have & () symbol,

first way,

```
$event_details = get_page_by_title($event_name, OBJECT, 'tribe_events');
```

second way,

```
$event_name = html_entity_decode( $event_name );
$event_details = get_page_by_title($event_name, OBJECT, 'tribe_events');
```

Third way,

```
global $wpdb;
$search = $wpdb->query( "SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `enter code here`post_title=".$title );
```

Fourth way,

```
$event_name = addslashes ( $event_name );
$event_details = get_page_by_title($event_name, OBJECT, 'tribe_events');
```

Comment: issue is : Ampersands in posts get changed to &amp; when saved to the database. This causes get_page_by_title to return null when using a title with an ampersand. https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/25157

Answer (score 0):

Just use `esc_attr()` for the title and also try to use `esc_html()`

```
$search = $wpdb->query( "SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `enter code here`post_title='".esc_attr($title)."'" );
```